# accessing a json list inside another list in python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a json file which I want to convert into csv,here are my codes

```
data=[]
with open('filename.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
f=csv.writer(open('filename.csv','wb+'))
for item in data:
    f.writerow([item['locations'][0]['time']])
```

The json contains three more lists inside and each list has the same attribute names. I can only access data in the first list; when I change `f.writerow([item['locations'][0]['time']])` to `f.writerow([item['locations'][-1]['time']])` it gives me access to the first and third lists (writing the first and third lists to csv) but it skips the second list. How can I access all the attributes in each of the lists, list 1-3?

Here is part of a single line of my json file

```
locations:[
{time : 1439319674334
longitude : 1.070336
local_time : "20:01:14:334 11 08 2015 +0100 GMT+01:00"
latitude : 51.2997804},
{time : 1439319694428
longitude : 1.0703332
local_time : "20:01:34:428 11 08 2015 +0100 GMT+01:00"
latitude : 51.2997889},

{time : 1439319714638
longitude : 1.0703123
local_time : "20:01:54:638 11 08 2015 +0100 GMT+01:00"
latitude : 51.2997794}
```

Comment: Is the `locations ` one of the key in the JSON object you have in the file. Also I think key you mentioned are string with quotes `"` for example: `"time"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd make your life much easier using the csv library.  Here try this

Try this:

```
In [75]: import csv
In [70]: j = {'locations':[
    ...: {'time' : 1439319674334,
    ...: 'longitude' : 1.070336,
    ...: 'local_time' : "20:01:14:334 11 08 2015 +0100 GMT+01:00",
    ...: 'latitude' : 51.2997804},
    ...: {'time' : 1439319694428,
    ...: 'longitude' : 1.0703332,
    ...: 'local_time' : "20:01:34:428 11 08 2015 +0100 GMT+01:00",
    ...: 'latitude' : 51.2997889},
    ...:
    ...: {'time' : 1439319714638,
    ...: 'longitude' : 1.0703123,
    ...: 'local_time' : "20:01:54:638 11 08 2015 +0100 GMT+01:00",
    ...: 'latitude' : 51.2997794}]}
    ...:
    ...:
In [74]: with open('output.csv', 'wb+') as f:
    ...:     writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=j['locations'][0].keys())
    ...:     writer.writeheader()
    ...:     for item in j['locations']:
    ...:         writer.writerow(item)
```

You get output like this:

[image: csvout (might be broken)]

Comment: thanks Kelvin for a quick response,so far I can manage to write the csv as in your results,my question is,how can i put the three lists in a single row?,like 'latitude 1','local_time1','longitude1','time1','latitute2','local_time2','longitude2'....in a single line not three lines

Comment: @DEOGRATIASMZURIKWAO that is much more involved.  Sorry, that wasn't what I got from the question.  I can try to take a look maybe later, but at the moment I don't have the bandwidth to write a full solution :\

Comment: Its ok,but it was very helpful.I was trying to use the above concepts to convert a json file using th for loop and having the same result csv format as yours and i was expecting to be easy since i manage with a single line,the file is having around 10,000 lines,help will be appreciated.

Comment: @DEOGRATIASMZURIKWAO, I can try to help, or you may want to put up another question with those specifics in it.  Someone might be able to help.  One of the biggest challenges isn't necessarily stringing them together, its the headers for your columns.  I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to achieve and it would be better with a full format for examples over just comments.  I'll definitely try to help!

Comment: ,I managed to convert the whole file now by looping and convert one line at time and it works fine,thanks all

Answer (score 0):

This single line can be converted into csv by following code:

```
locations:[
{time : 1439319674334
longitude : 1.070336
local_time : "20:01:14:334 11 08 2015 +0100 GMT+01:00"
latitude : 51.2997804},
{time : 1439319694428
longitude : 1.0703332
local_time : "20:01:34:428 11 08 2015 +0100 GMT+01:00"
latitude : 51.2997889},
{time : 1439319714638
longitude : 1.0703123
local_time : "20:01:54:638 11 08 2015 +0100 GMT+01:00"
latitude : 51.2997794} ]

file = open("filename.csv","a")

file.write("time, longitude, local_time, latitude\n")    

for location in locations:
    st = location['time'] + "," + location['longitude '] + "," + location['longitude'] + "," + location['latitude '] + "\n"
    file.write(st)
```

Comment: file open without a context manager, and writing csv files yourself is very bad practice.